# Is $(X^2-2,7)$ a prime ideal or maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Using the third isomorphism theorem, we find
$$
\Big(\mathbb{Z}[X]/ (X^2-2)\Big)/\Big( (X^2-2,7)/(X^2-2)\Big) \cong \Big(\mathbb{Z}[X]/ (X^2-2)\Big)/(7) 
$$
and
$$
 \Big(\mathbb{Z}[X]/ (X^2-2)\Big)/(7)  \cong (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})[\sqrt2],
$$
but this doesn't really help. Any insights or hints?

Comment: $3^2\equiv2\pmod7$

Answer (score 6):

I mean, you are basically there. You just thought about the last part wrong.

As you noticed

$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(7,x^2-2)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^2-2)$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, to verify the last quotient is a field/domain you must only prove that $x^2-2$ is irreducible. But, degree two polys are irreducible over a field if and only if they have no root in the field. Does $x^2-2$ have a root in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 2):

We can also show directly that the considered ideal is not prime:

Notice any element of $(X^2 -2, 7)$ of degree one is of the form $cX+d$ with $7|c$.

However, $(X-3)(X+3) = X^2 -9 \in (X^2 -2, 7)$.